# Flutter: Column align items to have the same width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to align the widgets inside the column to be in the center with CrossAxisAlignment.center but I also want that the Widgets have the same width. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you can get something similar to that by setting the `CrossAxisAlignment` to stretch and then wrap the `Column` in a `IntrinsicWidth` and if you want to give them a specific width use the `stepWidth` property

```
Center(
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("hello"),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("another hello"),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("DB"),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]