# Make buttons in a row have the same width in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

If I want to make two or more `Buttons` in a `Row` to have the same `Width`, how do I make it?
For examples I have three `RaisedButtons` with different title let say `Approve`, `Reject` and `Need Revise` and if I put the three `Button`s in a `Row`, they will have different `Width` and I don't want it. 
What I need is for they have the same `Width`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430798/how-to-layout-a-column-of-buttons-with-their-widths-equal-to-the-width-of-the-wi

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can use a `Row` wrapping your children with `Expanded`:

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Approve'),
        onPressed: () => null,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Reject'),
        onPressed: () => null,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Need Revise'),
        onPressed: () => null,
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks I was using Flexible earlier, but using Expanded instead of Flexible solved y issue. Thanks

Comment: how about if we want to make same size in a column ?

Comment: Hii how can i add space between button?

Comment: @coderInrRain check this link for your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684730/flutter-column-align-items-to-have-the-same-width

Comment: I have 7 buttons in a row. A row can have only 2-3 buttons as per available width of mobile. Kindly suggest me how can I wrap multiple buttons in row automatically? Thank you.

Comment: @NiharDodiya You can add space between buttons using SizedBox(width : <double number>),

Comment: and how to let those buttons have the same height ?

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways:

1. Expanded widget it will divide space in equal parts. If you use
   all expanded widget for row of column.
2. Get the width of the screen and divide it into the required sizes equally.

> Double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

Comment: I have 7 buttons in a row. A row can have only 2-3 buttons as per available width of mobile. Kindly suggest me how can I wrap multiple buttons in row automatically? Thank you.

Comment: @Kamlesh - If you change the Row into a Wrap widget (in combination with some of the suggestions on this thread), I think you will get the desired effect.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap you row with intrinsicWidth and button(any widget) with Expanded, this will give you all widgets with same width and width will equal to button with maximum size.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
           Expanded(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Approve'),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Reject'),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
         ),
         Expanded(
           child: RaisedButton(
             child: Text('Need Revise'),
             onPressed: () => null,
           ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can use new Buttons styles:

```
ElevatedButtonTheme(
      data: ElevatedButtonThemeData(style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(minimumSize: Size(120,60))) ,
      child: ButtonBar(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Although diegoveloper's answer is faster

Answer (score 0):

Use **minimumSize** of button in style property of Button in MaterialApp ThemeData widget to make button with same width in flutter:

```
        theme: ThemeData(
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            minimumSize: const Size(250, 50),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
        ),
      ),
    ),
```