# How to layout a column of buttons with their widths equal to the width of the widest one in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, layout

How can I make the following buttons the same width as the widest one (in this case the last one)?  I don't want to hardcode to make all equal to the last one, because, e.g., when switched to a different language, it might not be the last button that is widest.

[image: Column of buttons]

The code I am using:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(flex: 1),
        Text(
          'Flutter Test',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
        ),
        Spacer(flex: 2),
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Expanded(child: 
              Column(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                    },
                    child: Text('Apple'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                    },
                    child: Text('Banana'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                    },
                    child: Text('Chery'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                    },
                    child: Text('Durian'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text('Emu apple fruit'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Spacer(flex: 3),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, you don't need the `Row` and the `Expanded` widgets that you have used for the `Column` widget because they make no sense.

Now, to achieve what you're looking for can be done by wrapping the `Column` widget using the `IntrinsicWidth` widget and setting the `Column(property: crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`.

[image]

**The complete code should be as:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Spacer(flex: 1),
            Text(
              'Flutter Test',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
            ),
            Spacer(flex: 2),
            IntrinsicWidth(
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Apple'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Banana'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Chery'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Durian'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text('Emu apple fruit'),
                  ),
                ])),
            Spacer(flex: 3),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ElevatedButton` changes its width according to the length of the child string passed by `Text` widget, you can contain the elevated button in a `SizedBox` widget with the same width to all "sizedboxes" to get the same width on all of the buttons.

```
SizedBox(width: 200, child: ElevatedButton(child: Text('Apple'), onPressed: () {})),
SizedBox(width: 200, child: ElevatedButton(child: Text('Orange'), onPressed: () {})),
SizedBox(width: 200, child: ElevatedButton(child: Text('Emu Apple fruit'), onPressed: () {}))
```

you can choose the width to be any number you'd want to set the width to.

Comment: I don't want to fix the width.  Just want to be the same as the widest one, which just fit the text.

Answer (score 0):

try `layoutBuilder`, it detect the parent widget size and provides `constraints` that can be used by child.

hope you know the max width and can set the width using `constrains`
doest this help?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MaxWidthButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MaxWidthButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Spacer(flex: 1),
              Text(
                'Flutter Test',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
              ),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                          ),
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text('Apple'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth *.6,
                            child: Text('Banana'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth *.6,
                            child: Text('Chery'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Durian'),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text('Emu apple fruit'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Spacer(flex: 3),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double buttonWidth =100.0;
    double buttonHeight =20.0;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Spacer(flex: 1),
            Text(
              'Flutter Test',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
            ),
            Spacer(flex: 2),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Expanded(child:
                Column(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          width: buttonWidth,
                          height: buttonHeight,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Apple')
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          width: buttonWidth,
                          height: buttonHeight,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Banana')
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: buttonWidth,
                        height: buttonHeight,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Cherry')
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          width: buttonWidth,
                          height: buttonHeight,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Durian')
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          width: buttonWidth,
                          height: buttonHeight,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Emu apple fruit')
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(flex: 3),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
```