# Container fill width of Column with a dynamic width without affecting width of the column

Tags: flutter

How can I make an Element in a Column fill the width of the column, i.e. adapt the width of the widest element in the column?

```
Container(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      ...[0, 1].map(
        (e) => Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              // This container should fill the width of the column, without setting a constant width
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Text(
              "This is the widest element in the column",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: try to do this in Container: `width: double.infinity`. This will expand your Container's width as much as possible.

Comment: If you want to fit that Container exactly the widest element in Column and your widest element also has a dynamic width, it is impossible.

Comment: but the `Column` is inside the row, which provide infinite width. what exactly you are trying to build.

Comment: @Nguyenfamily `width: double.infinity` will make the container the element that dicates the width of the column but  I only want it to expand up to the width of the text. Then it looks like it is not possible in Flutter, as you said.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to layout a column of buttons with their widths equal to the width of the widest one in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430798/how-to-layout-a-column-of-buttons-with-their-widths-equal-to-the-width-of-the-wi)

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap Column with Expanded widget to take all available space in width of row

Answer (score 0):

Use **IntrinsicWidth** Widget as it sizes its child to the child’s intrinsic width. Means Wrap the column with **IntrinsicWidth** Widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
 Container(
child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
children: [
  ...[0, 1].map(
    (e) => Expanded(
      child:Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          // This container should fill the width of the column, without setting a constant width
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Text(
          "This is the widest element in the column",
        ),
      ],
    ),
      ),
  )
],
),
),
```

Comment: This just expands the Columns to maximum width but I don't want the Colums to use the maximum available width, I just want it to be as wide as it necessarily needs to be

Comment: If you want to make the cotainer, the same size of the succeeding Text widget's size. Use IntrinsicWidth instead of Expanded. Just try it out.